# How to convert JSON to CSV in batch command line with jq utility

Tags: batch, json

I need to extract a particular anti-virus product scan results from a JSON file and list the elements in csv format for further processing. JSON file sample like:

```
Contents of a file scanresults.json

{"scans": {"Bkav": {"detected": true, "version": "1.3.0.9899", "result": "W32.AIDetect.malware2", "update": "20230417"}, "Lionic": {"detected": true, "version": "7.5", "result": "Trojan.Win32.Generic.4!c", "update": "20230417"}, "Elastic": {"detected": true, "version": "4.0.85", "result": "malicious (high confidence)", "update": "20230413"}, "MicroWorld-eScan": {"detected": true, "version": "14.0.409.0", "result": "Trojan.Ransom.Cerber.1", "update": "20230417"}}}
```

The JSON organized the Anti-Virus scan results by products. It is required to retrieve results related to the product "Elastic" only in csv format for further processing as below:

```
detected, version, result, update
true, "4.0.85", "malicious (high confidence)", "20230413"
```

Base on my research, able to extract the result by jq command as shown below:

```
jq-win64.exe ".scans.Elastic" scanresults.json

{
  "detected": true,
  "version": "4.0.85",
  "result": "malicious (high confidence)",
  "update": "20230413"
}
```

Tried but failed to use map function to extract the needed results in csv format. The reference link used is https://earthly.dev/blog/convert-to-from-json/.

Thanks for provide solution and comments.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].